# Unable to sign In to Garmin through C# MVC website

Tags: c#, api, garmin

I have registered for Garmin API and able to get "Request Token" and "Request Token Secret" but when I try to confirm authorization i.e. when my application redirects a user to the sign in page of "Garmin connect" then even if user enters correct credentials, on signing in it shows `"Invalid sign in. (Passwords are case sensitive.)"`

On checking console I found below error:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://connecttest.garmin.com/oauthConfirm?oauth_token=""oauth_callback=""'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font
>   'http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTb3hpw3pgy2gAi-Ip7WPMi0.woff'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Can't understand what is wrong in this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I understand the problem comes from the font that is loaded over HTTP instead of HTTPS. In order to fix it, just remove http :

```
//themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTb3hpw3pgy2gAi-Ip7WPMi0.woff
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but how can I remove http from it, as I am not having this page at my end I am just constructing its URL. Would like to ask is this a real problem behind not getting logged in?

Comment: By removing http, you will let the browser define the correct schema to be used. Just construct your URL without the "http" and use it as it is.

Comment: I think you didn't get what I said, I am just constructing a url of page that contains a reference to this font, so I can not remove http from that font reference url. Also this page is not website's page it is a third party website's page whose url is what I am constructing and hitting.

Comment: Even if you construct this URL, you can always remove the http part even using a substring. The "//" part tells the browser to select the correct schema to call the URL, it undestands that it is a third party website.

Comment: Ok. I tried removing http from URL but still I'm getting "Invalid sign in. (Passwords are case sensitive.)" and the same error in console.

Comment: Good. For the password issue, are you able to connect to the garmin website, did you try to reset the password ? It seems Garmin has a lot of issues with the authorization process.

Answer (score 1):

The font would not cause invalid logins. Are you sure the user exist in the garmin TEST environment that you are using?

Its not the same database as production, youll need to create new separate accounts there.